# Applying max height to BottomSheetDialogFragment and apply height change transitions

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet, android-transitions

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` that holds multiple Fragments of different sizes as a content in the FrameLayout. 
The **max height** of the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` container needs to set at 60% of the total height of the current window viewport.

In addition, I also need to apply **transitions** when the content displayed within the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` changes its height such that the height changes smoothens out while rendering.

In other words, the height of the container should stay fixed no matter whatever the content displayed be in `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. And once the height of the content exceeds the height of the specified height, the content becomes scrollable. Said that, there can be content whose height is less than the max height and hence the transition should be applied to layout height changes.

Here's a layout hierarchy that matches what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_short_height" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_container"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!-- This layout always sticks to the bottom of the BottomSheet when opened -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <Button 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

PS: The view hierarchy still can be simplified but I am trying to use BottomSheetDialogFragment which can be used without specifying BottomSheetBehavior and so it's intended to avoid using CoordinatorLayout.

As per https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/

> Using BottomSheetDialogFragment provides a similar UI and interactions as BottomSheetBehavior, however BottomSheetDialogFragment does not require CoordinatorLayout and creates a modal bottom sheet (essentially a dialog).